# How to stop constant memory increase every time segment of code is run?

Tags: c#, loops, memory-leaks

I have a program that runs some methods every 5 seconds in the background. However every 5 seconds its physical memory usage jumps by 16-20 Kb. Through commenting out segments of code, I've narrowed it down to this specific segment is what is causing the issue. What am I missing here to correctly release the allocated Memory?

Loop segment from main method:

```
    while (true)
    {
        listMessages = FetchAllMessages();
        //Commented out other segments. Not causing memory increase
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
```

Method called:

```
    public static List<Message> FetchAllMessages()
    {
        try
        {
            using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
            {
                client.Connect("pop.gmail.com", 995, true);
                client.Authenticate("removed", "removed");
                int messageCount = client.GetMessageCount();
                List<Message> allMessages = new List<Message>(messageCount);

                for (int i = messageCount; i > 0; i--)
                {
                    if (verifiedEmail.Contains(client.GetMessage(i).Headers.From.Address) || verifiedSms.Contains(client.GetMessage(i).Headers.From.Address))
                    {
                        string tempMessage = client.GetMessage(i).ToMailMessage().Body.ToLower();
                        if (tempMessage.Contains("cmd") && tempMessage.Contains("fin"))
                        {
                            allMessages.Add(client.GetMessage(i));
                        }
                    }

                    client.DeleteMessage(i);
                }
                client.Disconnect();
                return allMessages;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: C# memory is garbage-collected.  At some point, all the unused memory will be returned by the garbage collector.  You can force this, but it's generally better to let the system do it in batches when it deems necessary.  Let your program run long enough, and you ought to see the memory use periodically plummet before building up again.

Comment: Honestly this is very little memory and you shouldn't really worry about it. I mean, the runtime itself already uses like 10MB.

Comment: I had let it run, but when I cam back to it about half an hour later it had gone from ~3,700 Kb to ~9,400 Kb. To me that seems like a much higher number than the GC system should allow.

Comment: That's still peanuts, as Zong pointed out.  You don't have good GC instincts yet.  Write code that uses more memory so you don't have to wait so long.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to debug the potential memory leak?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8517288/how-to-debug-the-potential-memory-leak)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the things that could be causing a steady increase in memory usage is that you're calling `GetMessage` so many times. Depending on how your POP client is written, that could be allocating a new buffer every time so that it can download the message from the POP server. That memory will of course be collected eventually, but you're exercising the garbage collector needlessly. And you're also being highly inefficient.

You should consider changing your code to something like this:

```
            for (int i = messageCount; i > 0; i--)
            {
                var msg = client.GetMessage(i);
                if (verifiedEmail.Contains(msg.Headers.From.Address) 
                    || verifiedSms.Contains(msg.Headers.From.Address))
                {
                    string tempMessage = msg.ToMailMessage().Body.ToLower();
                    if (tempMessage.Contains("cmd") && tempMessage.Contains("fin"))
                    {
                        allMessages.Add(msg);
                    }
                }

                client.DeleteMessage(i);
            }
```

So instead of calling `client.GetMessage(i)` four times, you call it only once.

It also makes the code easier to read.

That said, I think it's likely that your "memory leak" is just the GC taking its own sweet time in collecting memory.

One other thing. You have a sleep loop:

```
while (true)
{
    listMessages = FetchAllMessages();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

You're tying up a thread that spends most of its time doing nothing. You'd be better off creating a timer with a 5 second interval, like this:

```
System.Threading.Timer MailTimer; // declare at class scope

// Do this in your initialization
MailTimer = new Timer(MessageFetcher, null, 5000, -1);
```

And your MessageFetcher method is:

```
void MessageFetcher(object state)
{
    listMessages = FetchAllMessages();
    // do that other stuff that you didn't show

    // reset the timer so that it fires 5 seconds from now
    MailTimer.Change(5000, -1);
}
```

The initialization creates a one-shot timer that expires in five seconds and calls `MessageFetcher`. When `MessageFetcher` is done, it sets a timer so that mail will be checked in another five seconds. You want to do it this way rather than setting a periodic interval, because you don't want the timer to call `MessageFetcher` again if the previous tick isn't done processing.

The `MessageFetcher` method is executed on a pool thread. Using the timer prevents you from having to keep a thread around all the time, occupying memory while it's doing essentially nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As Paddy said, eventually garbage collection will get around to disposing the objects and releasing memory, but you CAN manually force it, although it's generally better to allow it to happen automatically.

But to test that garbage collection will reduce the memory, exit the `While` loop after several calls and call `GC.Collect();`.  The memory should go down.

Calling `GC.Collect();` is expensive and that's why you're better off to let the OS choose the optimal time to call garbage collection automatically.

This is a great answer to a similar question regarding your concerns: [C# Garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621848/c-sharp-garbage-collection)

> Who knows? It's not deterministic. Think of it like this: on a system
>   with infinite memory, the garbage collector doesn't have to do
>   anything. And you might think that's a bad example, but that's what
>   the garbage collector is simulating for you: a system with infinite
>   memory. Because on a system with sufficiently more memory available
>   than required by your program, the garbage collector never has to run.
>   Consequently, your program can not make any assumptions about when
>   memory will (if ever) be collected.
>
> So, the answer to your question is: we don't know.

I would recommend setting up a memory profiler to log the memory consumption of your application and run it for a while to test.  You should see that the Garbage Collector will keep things under control automatically without you having to change anything with your code.

Comment: I added a counter and exited the loop after 5 rounds. then called GC.Collect(); yet the memory did not decrease at all. it only climbed throughout.

Comment: You will need to let the memory build a lot more before you call GC.Collect();  Basically, you called GC.Collect() and it determined that it wasn't necessary to release any memory at that time because so little was in use.  As Zong Zheng Li said, 20 kb on a modern machine is pretty small.

Comment: My worry is that the code is intended to run for weeks if not months without being stopped or restarted. I'm watching the 20 Kb per 5 second increase and thinking of the implications say a month from now. What would be the level at which the GC system would begin to release memory then?